# Why is some RAM unusable by Windows 10?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-xp, memory

I have an IBM ThinkPad z61t with two 2GB DDR2 RAM cards.  Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit or Windows XP Professional 32-bit, all 4GB of RAM is used properly, however, running Windows 10 Professional 32-bit, the control panel says there's 4GB installed but only 3GB usable.  Why isn't Windows 10 using my RAM properly?  It works just fine in both Ubuntu and Windows XP.

Comment: Is this 32-bit Windows 10 or 64-bit?

Comment: "running Windows 10 Professional 32-bit, the control panel says there's 4GB installed but only 3GB usable." - The only way Windows XP was able to use 4GB was if you enabled PAE.  You can no longer do this with Windows 10.  Consider upgrading to the 64-bit version of Windows 10 instead, of course you likely will require a hardware upgrade, since that is unlikely to be possible with the hardware you have currently.

Comment: @ejbytes RAM isn’t subject to the “SI fraud”. When you buy 2 GB of RAM, you get 2 GiB of RAM. Actual RAM chip (not module) sizes are measured in Bit and come in powers of two.

Comment: @DanielB Neither was NASA subject to "SI fraud", but it happened. The point is that when you install RAM, you don't get to use all the RAM. That was the take away. It's like a car, your car doesn't just use gas when it's moving forward, it uses gas (RAM) when it's idling too. Are you now assuming that I don't really know about base 2? Wasn't this constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many laptops in the DDR2 era only had 32 address lines, resulting in a total of 4 GB physical address space, even when a 64-bit OS is running.  Your laptop, having a 945GM chipset, is one of them.

The result is that since mapped memories of peripherals such as the graphics processor (doesn't matter whether integrated or a separate chip) occupy a portion of this address space, only an amount of RAM equal to the address blocks which are not memory-mapped is actually addressable.

But some OSes reported the "Total RAM" as it was read from the memory modules, rather than the usable amount.  Those OSes can't actually use more, they just mislabel the "installed" amount and falsely suggest that it is all active.